# A flex script that matches empty inputs?

Tags: regex, string, flex-lexer, lex

Is it possible to write a `lex` or `flex` script containing a set of rules where the maximal-munch matching step will always match a length-zero string?

I ask this because the mathematical definition of regular expressions permits regular expressions that only match zero-length strings.  For example, the simple regular expression ε only matches the empty string.  However, the [flex pattern documentation](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html) doesn't seem to allow you to specify regular expressions of this form.

Comment: @agent-j I'm not sure I understand your comment - can you clarify what examples you'd like me to provide?

Comment: @templatetypedef: It nearly always makes things simpler to make a question concrete. Provide a sample input and expected output, and maybe even some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about lex, but flex can match the empty string by using a trailing context:

```
""/. { /* handle empty string */ }
```

This will match an empty string before any character, but it can be almost any pattern (see [flex documentation about limitations](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Limitations.html)).

```
<INITIAL>""/[-]{2} { BEGIN(sqlcomment); }
<sqlcomment>[^\n]* { /* Handle sql comment, including -- */ BEGIN(INITIAL); }
```

If you want to match the end of the input, you have to use the special symbol <<EOF>> (see [flex documentation about eof](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/EOF.html)).

*EDIT: Now that i think a little more about it, the trailing context might not be mandatory. Just "" may work. If it does, i still highly recommand to use a trailing context in this case when possible. It prevents many side effects with malformed inputs and helps debugging.*

Comment: You're absolutely right!  The script ""/.* matches the empty string infinitely many times.  Thanks for pointing this out!